# Как исправить конфликт BringIntoView и e.Handled?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не работает автопрокрутка (вертикальная) при отключеном автосдвиге(горизонтальной прокрутки при выделении с длинным названием item) горизонтальной панели.

Конфликт `e.Handled = true;` и item.BringIntoView

Как исправить конфликт BringIntoView и e.Handled ?

```
EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
<Setter Property="localModels:TreeViewItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True" />

private void TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Делаю всё как описано в примере.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589389/c-sharp-wpf-errorthe-name-treeviewitembehavior-does-not-exist-in-the-namespac

Но у меня не работает автопрокрутка scroll при выборе Item .

```
xmlns:localModels="clr-namespace:ChartsDisplayer2016.Core.DataSelector.Models;assembly=ModelAssemblyName"


<Grid >
<TreeView x:Name="tree" >

<TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView.Resources>

<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" >
        <Style.Resources>
        </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="localModels:TreeViewItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True" />
```

TreeViewItemBehavior

```
public static class TreeViewItemBehavior
{
    #region IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected

    public static bool GetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(
      TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TreeViewItemBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));

    static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(
      DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = depObj as TreeViewItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnTreeViewItemSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OnTreeViewItemSelected;
    }

    static void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only react to the Selected event raised by the TreeViewItem
        // whose IsSelected property was modified. Ignore all ancestors
        // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired.
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;

        TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        if (item != null)
            item.BringIntoView();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    #endregion // IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected
}
```